# Is there a way to get line numbers for tslint errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, web-essentials

I would like to get line numbers in Visual Studio for my tslint errors. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly but the line numbers are there in the Error list pane see screenshot, so you might need to right click and in the context menu there is an option called "Show columns" and add the line/column columns
[image]